# Over Query limit warning is showing on clicking the below link

Tags: node.js, google-api

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1301%20lombard%20street%20philadelphia

As i am new to this field i have gone through all of your answers but didn't understand. Can anyone tell me the solution in simple language.

Answer (score 0):

You've to generate a new `API key` for google maps

get an `API key` from this url https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key click on `get started`

Once you get it, update it in your code.

Here's an example update `YOUR_API_KEY` with the key you get from the link above.

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: in this it is asking for payment, i am unable to do that.....sir if u have any other way please suggest....otherwise it's ok.

Comment: Yeah actually it's paid but if you're using for development you can use free API key but it'll limit the API hits. The steps are correct what I mentioned above. Where are you using it? I mean the front end language?

Comment: i am using it to build a weather api using node.js